# emergency mode in ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

There was a problem with my laptop. It was necessary to remove Matlab in order to install a new one and it was not removed, so I removed it through the unlocker, rebooted the laptop, and could no longer log in, or rather, GRUB does not start. The screen shows that:

```
error: no such partition
```

(I have two Ubuntu partitions and Windows, but Ubuntu is the main one). After that, I managed to enter the GNU GRUB menu by using the commands:

```
set boot = (hd0, msdos5)
set prefix=(hd0, msdos5)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

But after entering Ubuntu, I was in emergency mode and was shown the error:

```
SGX disabled by BIOS
```

[image]

When I try to make at least an `apt-get update` or reinstall GRUB, this error  appears:

```
temporary error when obtaining an IP address ua.archive.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in particular, please clarify what "removed it through the unlocker" means